# Why can't we see who voted posts?

Tags: discussion

Pretty much self-explaining. What are the reasons behind not being able to see who upvoted or downvoted posts?

Comment: I think a neat feature related to this might be being able to use special callouts to notify those who voted. Something like: "@Downvoters Please check my edits and see if your downvote is still warranted". This would send a notification to anyone who downvoted and they could respond as they wish.

Comment: That's great! Have you suggested it? If so, please link here.

Comment: I have: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/909/can-we-implement-communication-with-voters

Answer (score 7):

[Voting is anonymous by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts) (see also [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139146/revealing-identity-of-those-who-vote-up-or-down/139147#139147)), although I'm having some difficulty tracking down an official word or SO meta discussion as to why. I'm fairly certain it has to do with two related things though:

- To keep the focus on the site on the questions (and answers) and their quality.
- To prevent retaliatory voting and/or comment drama.

If a user wants to reveal their vote, they can do so in a comment, and it's generally considered polite / good practice to comment on a downvote especially if you are the first person to do so.

Answer (score 4):

This is an unofficial best guess:

Negative votes are not meant to be taken personally but its very easy to do so even without knowing who did it. I think knowing who is down voting something could cause some unneeded drama such as

> "@UserWhoDownvotedMe - WHAT IS WRONG WITH YOU? My post is PERFECT!!!
>   Give me 27 good reasons that my post deserves a down vote!!!!"

And all of a sudden its personal all around when really the whole point of downvoting and closing questions is to keep the site on the right track. I think by exposing who is doing what voting there is going to be a lot of negative feelings towards certain users who consistently downvote things for the greater good of the site. These users will undoubtedly receive a lot of negativity from users and then probably just get fed up and leave the site which has a very negative impact on our community.